# how to bind this json data programitically in android , example i have mention below

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, arraylist

My json data from Server

```
 [
  {
    "status": [
      {
        "itemcode": "129652030900",
        "barcode": "129652030900^4500031080^20190919^10",
        "batchno": "4500031080"
      },
      {
        "itemcode": "129652030900",
        "barcode": "129652030900^4500031080^20190919^10",
        "batchno": "4500031080"
      }
    ],
    "Productlocation": "BAYLOC"
  },
  {
    "status": [
      {
        "itemcode": "129652030900",
        "barcode": "129652030900^4500031080^20190919^10",
        "batchno": "4500031080"
      },
      {
        "itemcode": "129652030900",
        "barcode": "129652030900^4500031080^20190919^10",
        "batchno": "4500031080"
      }
    ],
    "Productlocation": "BAYLOC"
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Its hard to understand what you are expecting. Post the code what you have tried

Comment: @dheeraj, Please check this document to ask the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/programming/json

Comment: @Subburaj i am using scanner device of Honeywell for making a module of item put-away in warehouse , first of all i have scan location than scan items , again scan location than items , until job card finished , i want add this data in json those i have mention in my example

Comment: Please edit your post to enrich its content with more detail. Don't describe your problem or what you've tried in comment.